# UIWebView's allowsInlineMediaPlayback property does not work on 4.2 on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, webkit, html5-video

I have a UIWebView with emebedded html5 videos. The webview instance has allowsInlineMediaPlayback set to NO, but this setting doesn't seem to working with 4.2 SDK both on the iPad simulator and the device - videos are still play inline on initialization unless I have a controls enabled and the full screen button is pressed.

I also tried calling the video.webkitEnterFullScreen() JS method on the  element on various video events but it seems like it only works if it specifically came on a user-inited action (onclick,touchstart etc..)

Anybody experiencing the same issues?

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior.

Comment: hi, you can refer to https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/ to get why "user-inited action"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO then calling video.webkitEnterFullScreen() ?